# Use of single-page sites to point to products?

Tags: ecommerce, woocommerce

I am contemplating creating a couple single page sites to point to a particular woocommerce item. Advantages are:

1. Can gear the content of the page to that single item for SEO and readability
2. Can create an easier URL for customers to remember

There would be a link such as “shop now” at the bottom of these pages to take the customer to the particular item directly.

Are there any down sides to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the type of strategy that I might have suggested 15 years ago, but which is unlikely to work well today.  There are several potential down sides:

- Google won't rank keyword rich domains now.   Years ago, having an exact match domain (EMD) was SEO gold.  Then [in 2012 Google released an EMD algorithm update](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-algorithm-history/emd-update/) and completely wiped one-page EMDs out of the top of the search results.
- Additional pages on your main site are likely to do better for SEO than pages on a separate domain.  The shared ranking signals of your bigger site make it easier to rank pages on it that pages on a brand new site.  I like to think of as "brand consolidation" is a ranking factor.
- Duplicate content could be another SEO problem. If you want this other domain to rank in addition to your main site, you will have to write completely different copy for it, or Google will choose not to index it.  Even similar or respun content can be low quality and unworthy of ranking to Google.
- From a technical standpoint, you can't share cookies between domains, so it is difficult to implement features across multiple domains that require you to know who the user is, or to have the user logged-in to both sites.

The only time I would recommend getting a memorable domain like this is when you are planning to promote it heavily in traditional media.   If you are advertising in print, on radio, and on TV, a such a domain can really help users be able to remember and type the URL.

Comment: Thanks  @stphen, I have been a webmaster since 1996 and remember these strategies well.  My main reason to do this is really for the memorable URL so people can pass the word more easily.  I just wanted to make sure that it would not be detrimental to my true web site.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to hurt your main website.